# Check radio button depending on variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, radio-button

I'm pretty new to jquery/javascript and am struggling with a radiobutton. I want the radio button to be checked depending on a variable coming from the database. I can see the value in my console, so it's dynamically filled, but I can't have the right radio button checked.

This is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //if ($('input[name="Gender"] option[value="%%Gender%%"]'))
        //  $('input[name="Gender"] option[value="%%Gender%%"]').prop("checked", true);
        if($('input[name="Gender"][value="%%Gender%%"]'))
        ($('input[name="Gender"][value="%%Gender%%"]').prop("checked",true))
      console.log("%%Gender%%");
      });
```

This is my table (I know it's not the way to work, but the html is generated and I have to use it) including the radio buttons:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
   <tr style="height: 20px">
      <td>
        <input type="radio" style="margin: 0px 4px 0px 0px; width: 13px;" name="Gender" id="control_COLUMN10_0" label="Gender" value="%%Gender%%">
      </td>
      <td class="defaultText" style="padding-right: 10px;">Male</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="height: 20px">
      <td>
         <input type="radio" style="margin: 0px 4px 0px 0px; width: 13px;" name="Gender" id="control_COLUMN10_1" label="Gender" value="%%Gender%%">
      </td>
      <td class="defaultText" style="padding-right: 10px;">Female</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Grts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried something like:

```
$('input[name="Gender"]').each(function( index ){
  if($(this).val() == "%%Gender%%")
     ($(this).prop("checked",true));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement appears to be missing curly brackets.

Both radio inputs have the same value, so the later will be checked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="Gender"]').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '%%Gender%%') {
      $(this).trigger('click');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
   <tr style="height: 20px">
      <td>
        <input type="radio" style="margin: 0px 4px 0px 0px; width: 13px;" name="Gender" id="control_COLUMN10_0" label="Gender" value="%%Gender%%">
      </td>
      <td class="defaultText" style="padding-right: 10px;">Male</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="height: 20px">
      <td>
         <input type="radio" style="margin: 0px 4px 0px 0px; width: 13px;" name="Gender" id="control_COLUMN10_1" label="Gender" value="%%Gender%%">
      </td>
      <td class="defaultText" style="padding-right: 10px;">Female</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```